# What's wrong with this Promotion Model?

Tags: svn, deployment, version-control

I was meeting with a customer, and they described how they promote code from dev to test to production using SVN.  What I heard really bothered me, and I've been thinking about it ever since.

I can't explain briefly why I think it's wrong - maybe you can help?

My goal would be to present some objective facts or measures that would convince the customer to change to something more, well, *normal*.  If I'm wrong, and this is a good way to go, then I'd like to know that as well.

Here's the process:

1. Changes are made in relation to individual tasks, and commits include the task ID in the commit message.
2. In order to promote code from one level to another, they query SVN by the task ID, and find the specific version of *each individual file* that was changed for that task.
3. They generate a script that checks out every one of the files from step #2 on the destination server.
4. Sometimes they want to deploy multiple tasks.  Their script goes through and reconciles the various file revisions needed among **all** of the tasks being promoted.

This customer doesn't use CI/CD tools.  They only deploy using this incremental approach.

Comment: What happens if file A is changed for Task ID 123 in revisions 5 & 7, for Task ID 456 in revision 6, and they want to deploy only task 123? Won't 456's changes be deployed as well? Cherry-picking individual files for deployment is an easy way to make a massive mess.  Are they doing any tagging or branching for these releases or tasks?

Comment: @alroc apparently no regular tagging is being done.  I have a feeling that they don't use branches in SVN because they can be expensive (compared to, e.g., git).

One other piece of information - currently they do only a few changes to each app per (day, week, whatever).

Their concurrency on each project is also very low (single-dev, maybe 2-3 people) and they specifically avoid dividing out tasks that touch the same file(s).

Comment: @mutty How are branches in Subversion *expensive*? A branch in Subversion takes up almost no space except for the changes on that branch -- just like in Git.

Comment: In your model, there may be no version of the code that the developers worked on that was actually deployed? I can't imagine that doesn't produce some embarrassing errors.

Comment: @DavidW. I think that's an important point to make.  I sort of made it during the discussion but the customer cited disk backups as a DR mechanism.  They also don't do local development - devs work on file shares to a server somehow.

Comment: Why not make almost all of changes on _task ID_ branches, and then merge those branches to the main development stream when they're needed? That'd be a lot easier than identifying individual files, and updating just those files.

Comment: Devs don't use Subversion? This is a big issue. The whole reason you have version control is for development. Why do the developers work on _shares_? This is a big red flag. Are the developers local? Can developers have access to Subversion?

Comment: @DavidW. Now you're getting it.  Devs do use subversion, they just don't have a local instance of the DB and web server set up (somehow!).  There's a whole bunch of stuff like this going on, and "it's just wrong" is not enough to convince them.  So while I agree with everything you're saying - *why* is it wrong?

Comment: The problem is simple: The three branch model they use adds complexity to their SDLC, but gives them nothing in return. Someone has to do all the branching and make sure it's done right. But, if the code has to be the same on all branches, why bother? I gave you a link to a document that explains how QA, UAT, Prod, and Development work on the same branch. I use this to get companies that think they need this particular model away from that thinking.

Comment: Their biggest issue isn't their branch strategy. It's the fact they update individual files, and they don't have a SVN revision that matches what's on production. They can't tag because there's no revision in Subversion that matches what they have. Tagging what's on production is important because you can quickly see what the difference was between now and then. It gives you an idea what was changed, and why. They have a manual error prone process. What issues are they running into, and how can you fix them? That's how you get them to change.

Comment: Tell them about using branches for each task. Then, when they want to deploy a particular task, they can merge that one branch. They can then have QA test it. If a bug is found, it can be fixed on the task branch, and remerged, or right on trunk. QA tests, and if deployment is approved, it's deployed right from trunk. Also, get them hooked on a CI engine like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org). Sounds like a PHP or JS shop, so there's no _build_ phase, but Jenkins can still be used for testing and packaging. Please tell me they're a JS/PHP shop, and not checking in compiled code into SVN.

Comment: @DavidW. the inability to clearly identify a repeatable test base seems like a huge problem to me, but again they don't perceive the problem.  To them, the existing process is fine.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with *promotion models* is that they create complexity, but that complexity doesn't add anything to the process. The purpose of branching is to allow for multiple development streams. In the promotion model, there is a single development stream, but now three branches are involved. Someone has to merge from one steam to another. QA and Production both must wait for that someone to do the promotion.

Even worse, there's not a 100% certainty that what development developed is what QA is testing, and what QA tested and approved is what is being placed into production. After all, QA and production are using two separate builds.

Let's simplify this a bit: Two branches, a *dev* branch and a *test* branch:

- QA is waiting for a new version on *test*.
- Finally Development gets around to promoting revision 90 to *test*. If everything went smoothly, what's on *test* is the same as revision 90 on *test*.
- QA tests the revision 90 that's on *test*. They find a bug and report it to Development.
- QA now waits for another promotion.
- Development fixes the bug in revision 100. They promote this build to *test*. Again, what's in revision 100 ***should*** be identical to what's on *test*.
- QA can now test revision 100 that's on the *test* branch.

What happens if we didn't have multiple branches?

- QA tests revision 90. This is identical to the revision on *test* above.
- QA finds a bug and report it to Development.
- Development fixes the bug in revision 100.
- QA now tests revision 100.

Same process except without all the branching voodoo going on. No one has to remember to promote a branch from one to the other. No one has to verify that one branch is the same as another.

Even more important, the software that the developers build in revision 90 is the same software that QA is testing. No need to rebuild the software and hope it's the same. When QA decides that a particular revision is okay for production, the same software that QA tested is promoted. No need to do a special build and *hope* it's the same that QA tested.

Think of it as this way, there is only a single development stream. Development is working on the tip of that development stream. QA is behind back in time testing an earlier revision. Production is even farther back in time using an even older revision.

In the end, all promotion branching does is add complexity to your development without adding any benefit. Life and development is complex enough as it is. No reason to make either one even more difficult.

Comment: I'm intimately familiar with many different types of SCM process.  The question wasn't about your personal opinion on one (straw-man) type of promotion model, of which there are many different approaches than the one you've outlined.  I'm really looking for an objective discussion about why no one ever does things the way these guys are doing it.

Comment: No one does it the way they're doing it because it's complex, unreliable, unpredictable and loaded with ways the wrong code can be deployed at the wrong time.

Comment: @alroc Totally agree.  But what can I point to other than my opinion?  "It's just wrong" isn't very consultative.

Comment: See my comment on the original post. Demonstrate how easy it is for something to be done wrong. Do a proof of concept with tagging and demonstrate the time (employee time especially) cost of managing the cherry-picking vs. tagging & branching. Demonstrate how their forced slow pace & rigid division of labor ultimately slows down delivery to the customer.

Comment: @alroc Yeah, all of those things are true, but there's an easy false equivalency that customers often take up by finding a tiny problem with the proposed approach as well.  What I'm *really* looking for is something objective and broadly accepted that says "nobody does that because it's really bad, and here's why".

Comment: Who is responsible for doing those promotions? When will they be done? What happens if there's a hotpatch? Do you now have six branches (three for the original stream and three for the hotfix?). How do you make sure that all of thee extra branches are maintained? What prevents someone from working on the wrong branch. Say patch _production_ in an emergency situation?

Comment: There are many different **legitimate** ways to use branching. A branch allows for parallel development. Some people put each change on an individual branch. Then, select the changes they want to incorporate. Adds a lot of complexity to the development process, but at the same time adds functionality to the process. For example, at the time of a release, you can decide whether or not to add a particular feature. I can't delve into the details in a single answer. The point is that you add a lot of complexity without adding functionality.

Comment: Let's not call in it _promotional_ branching. This is **branching-per-environment**. The main point is that it adds complexity. The reason a lot of places use it or push it is that many places can't imagine how it would work otherwise. If you can explain that QA, Test, and Development are all on the same stream, but in different moments in time, most places realize it's not needed. Here's a bit from a [document](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/433257/Branching%20Strategy.pdf) I use for proposals explaining how environment and streams work.